# Analysis plan using logistic regression

Tags: logistic

I am researching age at first sexual debut and HIV prevalence in Lesotho.  I want to analyse the data using logistic regression with SPSS.  My variables are age, sex, social status, education level, and environment.  How am I to allocate my variables?

Comment: Can you give us some rough idea of your sample size?

Comment: [This might help.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/how-to-deal-with-not-binary-categorical-variables-in-logistic-regression-spss)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "allocate"?  Some possible meanings are (1) where to collect data (experimental design), (2) how to partition data into training and testing sets, (3) how to identify the dependent variables (model selection).

Answer (score 2):

You will find help on allocating categorical variables with [UCLA's tutorials](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/dae/logit.htm).

```
logistic regression HIV with age sex
   /categorical = sex.
```

You might also find help [here](http://www.childrens-mercy.org/stats/weblog2004/categorical.asp).