# Association between a continuous and a categorical variable?

Tags: categorical-data, spss, continuous-data, association-measure

As it says in the title, what measure of association should I use for a categorical variable (with 4 groups) and a continuous variable (number of times travelled)?

I assume it can't be chi square as that is only suitable for nominal data.

Comment: Any measure of association would be based upon a predictive model, and that greatly depends on which variable is your dependent variable and which is your independent variable.

Comment: My IV is the categorical variable

Comment: This question may provide you with the answers you seek: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/how-to-deal-with-non-binary-categorical-variables-in-logistic-regression-spss